# Automatizing conversion dates to format YYWW

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert date by date all days **from the last week of 2016** to `YYYYWW` format.

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT date
  FROM UNNEST([
    DATE '2016-12-26',
    DATE '2016-12-27',
    DATE '2016-12-28',
    DATE '2016-12-29',
    DATE '2016-12-30',
    DATE '2016-12-31',
    DATE '2017-01-01']) AS date
)

SELECT
  date,
  CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%V', CAST(date AS DATE)) AS STRING) AS YearWeek,
  CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y', CAST(date AS DATE)) AS STRING) AS Year,
  CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%V', CAST(date AS DATE)) AS STRING) AS 
FROM Input 
ORDER BY date
```

All OK, until it reaches `2017-01-01`:

```
Row date    YearWeek    Year    Week     
1   2016-12-26  201652  2016    52   
2   2016-12-27  201652  2016    52   
3   2016-12-28  201652  2016    52   
4   2016-12-29  201652  2016    52   
5   2016-12-30  201652  2016    52   
6   2016-12-31  201652  2016    52   
7   2017-01-01  201752  2017    52
```

'`201752`' should be '`201652`'.

Best way to automate it for historical dates?

Something like this:

```
IF (REGEXP_EXTRACT(date,r'\d{4}-\d{2}-(\d{2})') = CAST('01' AS STRING)
    AND Week = CAST('52' AS STRING), Year-1, Year)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT DATE
  FROM UNNEST([
    DATE '2016-12-26',
    DATE '2016-12-27',
    DATE '2016-12-28',
    DATE '2016-12-29',
    DATE '2016-12-30',
    DATE '2016-12-31',
    DATE '2017-01-01']) AS date
)
SELECT
  date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%G%V', date) AS YearWeek  
FROM Input
ORDER BY date
```

Also Note - in your example:
1. You don't need to `CAST(date AS DATE)` as `date` is already of type DATE
2. You don't need `CAST(FORMAT_DATE(...) AS STRING)` as `FORMAT_DATE` already returns `STRING`

Answer (score 1):

`%Y` will return the calendar year for a date rather than the ISO year. To return the ISO year, which will be 2016 for January 1, 2017, use `%G` instead. See also [Supported Format Elements for DATE](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2017).